# Example of using NSTimer to move an Image?

Tags: xcode, swift, nstimer

Can anyone provide and example of how to use the NSTImer to move a UIImageView on Swift? I realize using animations ins the preferred method, but I can't get it to move smoothly and in the right coordinates. This is using xcode 7. Thanks

ATTENTION!!

I have edited and responded to Jacob to see further problem solving.

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Exchange Network, and more specifically Stack Overflow. Stack Exchange is a network of Q&A sites, and here on Stack Overflow, we're more than willing to help, it's always asked that you provide the code you attempted *before* while asking a question. More information on the system can be found [here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/) in the Help Center.

Comment: I don't think using a timer will be the best solution. Can you post your currently not working very well code here? So we can point you the right way

Comment: what you have try so far?

Comment: well someone showed me to use this   var timer = NSTimer()
    func someMethod() {
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target:self, selector: Selector ("mrock"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        
    }

But I dont know where to put code to move the Image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments I don't really think you want to use an NSTimer for this type of thing.

Have you tried:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
     //update frame of imageView to new desired location
}, completion: {
     //
})
```

Comment: I agree with Jacob. Core Animation or UIView animation is almost always better. NSTimers are pretty crude, and won't fire if your code is busy at the designated time. Thus you'll have stutters in your animations. This approach is also quite costly for the processor. Core Animation works with the tiled rendering engine in the hardware, and gives both smoother animation and less load on the processor. If your current animation code isn't smooth, post it here.

Comment: So Ill stop using the NSTimer since it is not recommended. If I use the code that Jacob mentioned, where would I place the code that moves the image? 
Like I want to move a 40, 40 pixel square from the top to the bottom, then repeat that action over a period of 3 seconds.
And where would I put the entire thing in the viewcontroller? There is no start button so would I put in in the viewdidload?